# Neo4j - Using Java plugins to REST api to improve performance?

Tags: performance, rest, neo4j

I am building an application that requires a lot of data constantly being extracted from a local MongoDB to be put into Neo4j. Seeing as I am also having many users access the Neo4j database, from both a Django webserver and other places, I decided on using the REST interface for Neo4j.

The problem I am having is that, even with batch insertion, the Neo4j server is active over 50% of the time with just trying the insert all the data from the mongoDB. As far as I can see there might be some waiting time because of the HTTP requests but I have been trying to tweak but have only gotten so far.

The question is, if I write a Java plugin (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html) that can handle inserting the mongoDB extractions directly, will I then go around the REST API? Or will the java plugin commands just convert to regular REST API requests? Furthermore, will there be a performance boost by using the plugin?

The last question is how do I optimize the speed of the REST API (So far I am performing around 1500 read/write operations which includes many "get_or_create_in_index" operations)? Is there a sweet spot where the number of queries appended to one HTTP requests will keep Neo4j busy until the next HTTP request arrives?

**Update:**

I am using Neo4j version 2.0

The data that I am extracting consists of bluetooth observations, where the phone that is running the app i created scans all nearby phones. This single observation is then saved as a document in MongoDB and consists of the users id, the time of the scan and a list of the phones/users that he has seen in that scan.

In Neo4j I model all the users as nodes and I also model an observation between two users as a node so that it will look like this:

(user1)-[observed]->(observation_node)-[observed]->(user2)

Furthermore I index all user nodes.

When moving the observation from mongoDB to Neo4j, I do the following for each document:

1. Check in the index if the user doing the scan already has a node assigned, else create one
2. Then for each observed user in the scan: A) Check in index if the observed user has a node else create one B) Create an observation node and relationships between the users and the observation node, if this doesn't already exist C) Make a relationship between the observation node and a timeline node (the timeline just consists of a tree of nodes so that I can quickly find observations at a certain time)

As it can be seen I am doing quite a few lookups in the user index (3), some normal read (2-3) and potentially many writes for each observation.

Each bluetooth scan average around 5-30 observations and I batch 100 scans in a single HTTP request. This means that each request usually contains 5000-10000 updates.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

The unmanaged extension would use the underlying Java-API so it much faster, also you can decide on the format & protocol of the data that you push to it.

It is sensible to batch writes, so that you don't incurr tx overhead per each tiny write. E.g. aggregating 10-50k updates in one operation helps a lot.

What is the concrete shape of the updates you do? Can you edit your question to reflect that?

Some resources for this:

- http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/09/05/scaling-writes/
- http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/12/31/the-power-of-open-source-software/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the articles! They were quite insightful. I have updated the question. Do you think this transfer from Mongo to Neo4j is something that would be beneficial to do using an extension than just a python script that calls the REST API?